# Popup UIPickerView

Tags: ios, xcode, uipickerview

I know lots of people have asked same question, and I've tried lots of them, I don't know what part that I miss, I still can get it to work.

I have a 9*9 table that I want to display and change, because of the size of Iphone Screen, I'm thinking to show one column a time.
What I want is to press the top left button and a UIPickerView will popup allows me to choose which column to display, then reload the UITextFields.

Can anyone give me a detailed answer? I'm still relatively new in this(couple months).
Thank you in advance.

[image: 9*9Table]

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil 
                                                delegate:nil
                                                cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                                destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                otherButtonTitles:nil];

[actionSheet setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent];

CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 40, 0, 0);

UIPickerView *pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
pickerView.dataSource = self;
pickerView.delegate = self;

[actionSheet addSubview:pickerView];


UISegmentedControl *closeButton = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray     arrayWithObject:@"Close"]];
closeButton.momentary = YES; 
closeButton.frame = CGRectMake(260, 7.0f, 50.0f, 30.0f);
closeButton.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
closeButton.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[closeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissActionSheet:)   forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[actionSheet addSubview:closeButton];
[closeButton release];

[actionSheet showInView:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]];

[actionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 485)];
```

Above is the code I found, it pops up alright, I have problem adding array to pickerview, and can anyone tell me how should dismissActionSheet method be?
Thank you.

Comment: Please post some code that you tried, it will be easier for us to help if we can see what you're doing wrong/what you're trying to do.

Comment: @mkral hi, sorry for the late update, I was working on something else last week. I updated my question and listed the code I used.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I think I understand what you are asking, correct me if this isn't what you need help with...but to add an array (of presumably NSStrings) to the picker view you need to use the `- (NSString *)pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent:` delegate method. Here is a quick examle:

```
//Say you have an array of strings you want to present in the pickerview like this
NSArray *arrayOfStrings = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"One", @"Two", @"Three", @"Four", nil];

//First we need to say how many rows there will be in the pickerview
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [arrayOfStrings count];
}

//Do the same for components (columns) in pickerview
    - (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 1;
}
//Here we set the actual title/string on the pickerview
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    if(component==0){
        //Grab the nth string from array
        return [arrayOfStrings objectAtIndex:row];
    }
}
//This is called if a user taps a row
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    if(component==0)
    NSLog(@"The User Selected the row titled %@", [arrayOfStrings objectAtIndex:row]);
}
```

Similairly with actionsheet, you need to add the delegate method for handling when a user clicks a button on the actionsheet

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if(buttonIndex==0){
        NSLog(@"First Button Clicked");
    } else if( buttonIndex == 1){
        NSLog(@"Second Button Clicked");
    }
}
```